# Change Href on browser size + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a responsive menu, when viewing on PC on a hover the menu drops, on a tablet obviously you cant hover so on click I need the menu to drop. However the link is directing the user to the page on the click. I need to prevent the link from firing on a click (on a specific browser size) so it can open a dropdown menu

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
  <li>
     <a href="page.html">Page</a>
     <ul class="subMenu">
       <li><a href="">Sub Page 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Sub Page 2</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="anotherpage.html">Another Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="anotherpage.html">Another Page</a></li>
  <li>
     <a href="page.html">Page</a>
     <ul class="subMenu">
       <li><a href="">Sub Page 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Sub Page 2</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This jQuery achieves the necessary hover and drop down

**jQuery**

```
    if ($bWidth > 1025) {
        $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
        });
    } else {
        $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().click(function () {
            $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
        });
    }
```

**Closest Attempt**

```
if ($bWidth > 1025) {
        $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
        });
    } else {
        $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            location.href = "javascript:void(0);";
            $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
            return;
        });
    }
```

This attempt is the closest ive come, however it stops all the nav links from executing, ive been trying to target the parent A of the subMenu it will open and close all submenus instead of just the 1 the user is clicking. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use [touch.js](http://html5quintus.com/docs/touch.html) which allows you to use touch and drag events

Comment: id like to do this without plugins i've written a lot so far this seems like a minor targeting error fix, i just cant figure out the solution at this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to event.preventDefault() on the click. Also there is a nice tutorial here. preventDefault on an anchor tag will stop the href from firing. Also, what version of jquery are you using? I'd suggest using .on and .off instead of bind and unbind. Also, set the events to a better selector. $("parentSelector").on("event", "actual selector", function(){

});

[see this demo](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly)

Comment: i used preventDefault to stop the click but it stopped ALL clicks, just trying to stop the anchor in the .mainMenu li

Comment: It will probably need a event.stopPropagation. Sounds like its bubbling up the dom tree. Also, the selector used is an li object not an a tag object, so when you say unbind and prevent default, you are preventing the li click, which in touch devices would prevent the hover effect.

$('.mainMenu > li > a')

Comment: try this fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/Cf6kN/ can add what you need later, but i am thinking this is what you are after.